# Root directory not changing (EasyPHP)

Tags: php, apache, directory, root, easyphp

Having a project with `index.php` inside `public_html/` folder, I was looking to change the root directory of EasyPHP, so this is what I did:

[image]

But when going to `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`), EasyPHP always display the root directory:

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `VirtualHost` as well at the end of the `conf_files\httpd.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "${path}/data/localweb/public_html"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    <Directory "${path}/data/localweb/public_html">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Regards

Comment: Btw, instead of changing DocumentRoot, you should use Aliases or Virual Hosts.

Comment: It works. You will need to change:  

DocumentRoot "C:/Projects"  
<Directory "C:/Projects">  

Thanks!